# If $\lambda$ has algebraic multiplicity $m$ has $\lambda^k$ the same multiplicity?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $\lambda$ a eigenvalue of $A$ with the algebraic multiplicity equal to $m$.

I know that $\lambda^k$ is an eigenvalue of $A^k$. What can I say about its algebraic multiplicity?

Comment: It may increase, consider for example $A = \big[\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & -1\end{smallmatrix}\big]$ and $λ = 1$.

Comment: Related question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856109/if-k-is-an-eigenvalue-of-a-of-algebraic-multiplicity-r-then-is-pk-an?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda^k$ with respect to $A^k$ will be the sum of the algebraic mulitplicities of eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $A$ such that $\lambda_i^k=\lambda^k$.

The proof uses the Jordan canonical form.